# How to separate date in year, month and day in r

Tags: r, date, data-analysis, data-science

I have a date variable in a data frame with date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

I used the separate function(below) in `tidyr` package which worked but it does not add columns to the table.

```
separate(<table name>, "<date variable>", c("Year", "Month", "Day"), sep = "-")
```

How can I get "Year", "Month" & "Day" variables added to the end of the table?

Comment: You need to assign? ie. `df <- separate(df, ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define

- the data frame as first, and
- the column with the date as second

argument to `separate`.

See this example:

```
d <- data.frame(date = c("2017-02-23", "2017-02-22"))
separate(d, "date", c("Year", "Month", "Day"), sep = "-")
```

Which yields:

```
  Year Month Day
1 2017    02  23
2 2017    02  22
```